# How do we make part of the route optional in Expressjs?

Tags: express

How do I make a part of the route(not just parameters) as optional? 
For example in:

```
\pid\:pid\did\:did
```

If `did` is not present `:did` should not be present.

How do I go about writing a route for this?

Comment: A not really straightforward way would be to use regular expressions in the route path. A much simpler way would be to accept them as url parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement, you have to create two end point.

1. `/pid/:pid`
2. `/pid/:pid/did/:did`

This will solve your problem.